# How to use OpenGL and GLSL to change color (C++)?

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl, glut, shader

I am working on an OpenGL project in C++, and I want to learn how to use GLSL shaders. The problem is that, while I can complete my program without using my own shaders, I want to write my own (at this time there are no shaders that I load myself - not sure if OpenGL defaults any).

To draw a bunch of lines on the image (whose vertices are stored in a vector and color values are stored in another vector), I use the following code to run through and render them whenever the frame is updated - I use the GLUT display function for this.

```
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
glBegin(GL_LINES);  
vector<point2>::iterator it;
int c_index = 0;
for(it=points.begin(); it<points.end(); it++){
    if(c_index % 2 == 0) //set color for every pair of points (each line)
        glColor3f(colors[c_index/2][0], colors[c_index/2][1], colors[c_index/2][2]);
    c_index++;

    glVertex2f(it->x, it->y); //set vertex
}
glEnd();
glFlush();
```

Now, the problem is when I try to use shaders that I found in another example program, the color is all red (even though the shaders do not explicitly define any colors). It also makes glColor3f do nothing.

My question is, assuming I can use shaders to do this, what do the shaders have to look like, and how would I load them?

Comment: What version of GLSL are you using? (if you don't use a #version in your shader code, it's probably GLSL 1.10.)

Comment: This particular code snippet is of no interest when it comes to shaders. The code we need to see are the shader itself, the shader object creation code and uniform and attribute bindings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently it cannot be done using glColor3f. Instead, I had to make a pre-determined OpenGL buffer, and send the buffer data to the shaders. It can't be done "on the fly" as I hoped.